# PHP regex check if contains a specific word but doesn't contain another

Tags: php, regex

How can I check using PHP regular expressions, whether my string variable $str contains the word 'cat' but does not contain the word 'dog'.

- Case 1: $str = "My pet: parrot" -> Output: false
- Case 2: $str = "My pet: dog and cat" -> Output: false
- Case 3: $str = "My pet: cat" -> Output: true

I have tried this and it works but I was wondering if there was a single regular expression to do it

```
$str = "My pet: dog and cat";
if (preg_match('/(\bdog\b)/', $str) && !preg_match('/(\bcat\b)/', $str)) echo 'TRUE';
else echo 'FALSE';
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a negative and a positive lookahead for this:

```
^(?=.*?cat)(?!.*?dog).*$
```

To check for complete words use `\b`:

```
^(?=.*?\bcat\b)(?!.*?\bdog\b).*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gQ1fU9/1)

Comment: I tried this preg_match('^(?=.*?\bcat\b)(?!.*?\bdog\b).*$', $str) but I am getting an error: No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: You have to use: `preg_match('/^(?=.*?\bcat\b)(?!.*?\bdog\b).*$/', $str);`